# How to configure group of services by namespace in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony5

In the default Symfony 5 config, I looking this:

```
services:
    ...
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Exception,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    ...
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

It looks very cool. As if I can configure some default settings for a group of services by namespace, like that

```
    ...
    App\Service\MySpecialTaskServices\:
        resource: '../src/Service/MySpecialTaskServices/*'
        public: true
        ... other default params\args for this NS ...
```

But this stuff not work: configuration loaded correctly, but parameters can not be applied.

May be I doing something wrong? It's bad idea, clogging services.yaml with a bunch of services with the same params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good reason, with using custom tags functionality. Maybe it help someone else.

1. Instantiate you services in group from single interface/abstract
2. Add _instanceof option in services.yml in global services: block

```
services:
    _default:
        ....
    _instanceof:
        App\Service\MySpecialTaskServices\MySpecialTaskInterface:
            tags: ['app.public_service']
```

3. Define a custom compiler pass for support you new tag with this process method

```
class PublicServicesGroupPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    ...
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $services = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.public_service');
        foreach (array_keys($services) as $id) {
            $definition = $container->findDefinition($id);
            $definition->setPublic(true);
            // other works with params
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

4. And register them in your kernel

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    ...
    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new PublicServicesGroupPass());
    }
    ...
}
```

And this working correct. But I would like to make it easier.